# Save columns and rows configuration in the Webdatarocks

Tags: angular, webdatarocks

I'm using the Webdatarocks in my web app (angular 2, spring boot).
The problem is that I must re-configure the columns and the rows of the Webdatarocks each time.
I want to save some configurations that I can choose directly.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Use [getReport()](https://www.webdatarocks.com/doc/getreport/) API call, which returns all current configurations of the pivot. Then you can process this report, leaving only needed configurations. New columns and rows should be added within the [slice](https://www.webdatarocks.com/doc/slice-object/) object of your report.